# Weird problem with mic signal bleeding into speakers

Tags: microphone, signal

So this is a very strange problem. Sometimes, pretty rarely whenever I am actively using my mic I can hear myself in the speakers repeat what I've said a couple of seconds ago. I've been trying for a long time to figure out what was the cause of that. I even ended up reinstalling Windows/sound drivers in hopes to fix it but it still happens sometimes. It only happens on my newer PC and never happened on the old one. Could it because of a faulty onboard audio?

EDIT:
It happened in TS3, Skype and Discord. I used 3 different headsets during the last year - Corsair VOID, Corsair VOID wireless and now I'm using Logitech G933 and it still happens. Like I said I am pretty lost here since it happens in all kinds of programs and with all kinds of headsets. I was thinking it might be my onboard Realtek 1150 soundcard but USB headsets such as mine don't even use it as they have their own sound processing built-in

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask this question without actually giving any details of the application you are using. This is a frequent phenomenon with applications like Skype since the connections to your partner and back constitute a delay line and the speaker will feed into the other's microphone when he isn't using a headset. A "couple of seconds" is quite beyond what even the worst audio setups deliver as time lag, so it seems less likely that your problem is purely local, at least unless we are talking about a very specific setup and application, and you mention none at all.

Comment: I should have included it from the start. It happened in TS3, Skype and Discord. I used 3 different headsets during the last year - Corsair VOID, Corsair VOID wireless and now I'm using Logitech G933 and it still happens. Like I said I am pretty lost here since it happens in all kinds of programs and with all kinds of headsets. I was thinking it might be my onboard Realtek 1150 soundcard but USB headsets such as mine don't even use it as they have their own sound processing built-in

Comment: Also, the only thing that unites these headsets is virtual dolby surround. But I never heard of anyone having this kind of problem with dolby.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your voice messaging partner to use a headset rather than loudspeakers.  This is nothing you can fix at your end of the connection.

Comment: It is definitely not it though. Once I started talking in an empty TS3 channel thinking my mate is there and a couple of words got back to me.